# Play framework "play.filters.enabled" cannot work if "play.http.filters" is set

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am using play framework 2.8.16.

I defined Filters.scala in my application and enable it in application.conf

```
play.http.filters = com.xxx.xxx.Filters
```

I have another setting

```
play.filters.enabled += play.filters.https.RedirectHttpsFilter
```

RedirectHttpsFilter will be ignored.

Is it expected? How to support both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected and [documented](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Filters#Default-Filters).

> Play comes with a default set of enabled filters, defined through configuration. If the property `play.http.filters` is null, then the default is now `play.api.http.EnabledFilters`, which loads up the filters defined by fully qualified class name in the `play.filters.enabled` configuration property.
>
> (...)
>
> You can also combine `EnabledFilters` with your own filters in code:
>
> Scala:
>
> ```scala
> class Filters @Inject() (enabledFilters: EnabledFilters, corsFilter: CORSFilter)
>    extends DefaultHttpFilters(enabledFilters.filters :+ corsFilter: _*)
> ```
>
> Java:
>
> ```java
> public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {
>
>   @Inject
>   public Filters(EnabledFilters enabledFilters, CORSFilter corsFilter) {
>     super(combine(enabledFilters.asJava().getFilters(), corsFilter.asJava()));
>   }
>
>   private static List<EssentialFilter> combine(
>       List<EssentialFilter> filters, EssentialFilter toAppend) {
>     List<EssentialFilter> combinedFilters = new ArrayList<>(filters);
>     combinedFilters.add(toAppend);
>     return combinedFilters;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Otherwise, if you have a `Filters` class in the root or have `play.http.filters` defined explicitly, it will take precedence over the `EnabledFilters` functionality described below.

If you change the value of `play.http.filters` configuration to your custom class, then all the logic to add/remove filters with `play.filters.enabled` is not applied anymore.

Either:

- stick to configuration file only filters with the default mechanism,
- or inject `EnabledFilters` in your `com.xxx.xxx.Filters` to support both,
- or load all filters from your `com.xxx.xxx.Filters` class (this would mean also the ones declared in default config files of Play, not recommended).